# Display meta values from a table

Tags: mysql

I would like to display all of the meta values from a particular table and need to establish the SQL query to achieve this.

Here is the structure;

- All forms exist under `wp_frm_forms`
- All Fields within the form exist in `wp_frm_fields`
- Each submission is stored in `wp_frm_items`
- All values from the wp_frm_items are stored in `wp_frm_items_metas`

A form is completed on the site which has an ID to separate it from the other forms I use. In this particular case I want to display all `wp_frm_items_metas` as the column headers WHERE the `wp_frm_forms.ID = 6`

They need to be grouped by the `wp_frm_item_metas.item_id` which is the common value for all meta items that relate to that submission.

The structure of each table is as follows;

[image: wp_frm_forms]

[image: wp_frm_fields]

Comment: Don't post images, paste plain text into the question. To keep them formatted, mark it with the mouse and then click on the `{ }` tool or type Control-k to mark it as code.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried. We're not going to write this for you, but we'll help you fix what you've tried.

Comment: We need to see the table definitions for your tables to help you in any specific way. Also, the tech jargon for your requirement is a *pivot* report, where rows in a table are pivoted to columns. That is a notoriously difficult thing to do in MySQL.  This looks like WordPress, so you may want to investigate doing the pivoting in PHP instead. Your form plugin may have what you need.